# HTML title & meta description vs. Schema.org title and description

Tags: html, schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

Should the text entered as the `description` (a Schema.org property) be set as the `meta`-`description` of the HTML page?

Consider the following content:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "JobPosting",
  "baseSalary": "100000",
  "jobBenefits": "Medical, Life, Dental",
  "datePosted": "2011-10-31",
  "description": "Description: ABC Company Inc. seeks a full-time mid-level software engineer to develop in-house tools.",
  "educationRequirements": "Bachelor's Degree in Computer Science, Information Systems or related fields of study.",
  "employmentType": "Full-time",
  "experienceRequirements": "Minumum 3 years experience as a software engineer",
  "incentiveCompensation": "Performance-based annual bonus plan, project-completion bonuses",
  "industry": "Computer Software",
  "jobLocation": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "addressLocality": "Kirkland",
      "addressRegion": "WA"
    }
  },
  "occupationalCategory": "15-1132.00 Software Developers, Application",
  "qualifications": "Ability to work in a team environment with members of varying skill levels. Highly motivated. Learns quickly.",
  "responsibilities": "Design and write specifications for tools for in-house customers Build tools according to specifications",
  "salaryCurrency": "USD",
  "skills": "Web application development using Java/J2EE Web application development using Python or familiarity with dynamic programming languages",
  "specialCommitments": "VeteranCommit",
  "title": "Software Engineer",
  "workHours": "40 hours per week"
}
</script>
```

Should the text entered as the content of the property `description` ("ABC Company Inc. seeks a full-time mid-level software engineer to develop in-house tools.") be set as the value of the `meta`-`description` tag in the `head` section of the HTML page as shown below:

```html
<meta name="description" content="ABC Company Inc. seeks a full-time mid-level software engineer to develop in-house tools.">
```

In the same way, what about setting the content of the Schema.org property `title` to the `title` element (in the `head` section) of the HTML page shown as below:

```html
<title>Software Engineer</title>
```

Comment: Although this is published in such a manner found in the thread: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/can-meta-description-and-schema-description-be-the-same , I need specific answer for the given sample code that is going to be published as the code of an online job portal.

Comment: It’s off-topic here to ask what is better for SEO, so I would suggest you [edit] your question and remove the whole second part.

Comment: Or, better still, delete this and ask on Webmasters.SE (SEO is off-topic here)